# Cloned form's php being output as plain text

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to clone some html using jquery.

It's working fine but the php it clone is being output as plain text.

Any ideas how I can change this?

Here's a jsfiddle of what i've got so far http://jsfiddle.net/vs8p5/5/

Here's the jquery

```
function updateClonedInput(index, element) {
$(element).appendTo("body").attr("id", "clonedInput" +  index);
$(element).find(">:first-child").attr("id", "show_upload_image_link_" + index);
$(element).find(">:first-child").attr("name", "kandibox_theme_hero_options[show_upload_image_link_" + index + "]");
$(element).find(">:first-child").attr("value", "<?php echo $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_" + index + "']; ?>");
$(element).find(">:first-child").next().attr("id", "show_upload_image_link_button_" + index);
}

$(document).on("click", "button.clone", function(){
var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length + 1;
var new_Input = $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone();
updateClonedInput(cloneIndex, new_Input);    
});
$(document).on("click", "button.remove", function(){
$(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();

$(".clonedInput").each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
updateClonedInput(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
})
});
```

Here's the html form

```
<div id="upload_image_sets">
  <div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
  <input type="text" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_image_link_1]" value="<?php echo $hero_options['upload_image_link_1']; ?>" /> 
  <input id="show_upload_image_link_button_1" class="button upload_images" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
    <div class="actions">
      <button class="clone">Clone</button> 
      <button class="remove">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: PHP is working on SERVER - after the page is load. JS is working on CLIENT SIDE - in browser. So You cant use code like this:
<?php echo $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_" + index + "']; ?>
You cant use JS vars in PHP!

Comment: That's fair enough, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Are You sure that You are using PHP? :) When generating JS and PHP the PHP part shoud be change to values of Your vars. In Your case it should return error, because of using JS vars in PHP. I dont know full vision of Your script, but to clear values do like this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vs8p5/21/)

Comment: Thanks for that, that worked when cloning but removing resulted in the all the forms clearing, once i deleted the line $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("value", ""); it works, it do't give me a clean form after the clone but i'll change that anyway

Answer (score 0):

In order to output like php remove the "" around the php code:

```
 $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("value", <?php echo $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_" + index + "']; ?>);
```

Otherwise it does not read the actual php, it automatically converts it to HTML text.

I also noticed that you are inserting jquery between the php code. You will have to close the code before outputting jquery. If the above still works incorrectly. This should do the trick:

```
$(element).find(">:first-child").attr("value", <?php echo $hero_options['show_upload_image_link_?>index<?php ']; ?>);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi I tried the code but without having the quotes, it bring up a syntax error.